# $_SESSION value changing only in firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a page (customer.php) where I set the `$_SESSION['token']`:

```
$token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
```

that I use in the form on that page for CSRF checking. The form is submitted through jQuery's $.ajax to a php file (customerHandler.php):

```
if(isset($_POST['function']) && $_POST['function'] == 'sendRequest') {
    $result = Customer::filter($_POST['token'], trim($_POST['filter_name']), trim($_POST['filter_flag']), $_POST['page'], $_POST['per_page']);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

**Customer::filter -**

**Customer.class.php**

**filter()** is a method in that class.
This is where I check the CSRF token that was set in `$_SESSION`. What's confusing me is that the value of `$_SESSION['token']` changes. And it changes ONLY in Firefox. In Chrome, it is just okay. I wonder why `$_SESSION['token']`'s value changes even though the page (customer.php - where I generate token) isn't reloaded because I'm using $.ajax...
Any idea why this is happening...?

Comment: can you add more code ?

Comment: Didn't you forget `session_start()`?